# How to use "closure" to assign objects asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

**EDIT**: The kind people of this site linked me to a QA that seems related to the problem described below.

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

While I appreciate the prompt response, and I can understand the need to prevent duplicate content, it leaves me in a pickle - I'm not savvy enough to understand how to repurpose the linked answers to solve my particular problem.

I've modified the question to be more specific - please consider helping me rectify my inexperience this time, instead of leaving me to fend for myself.

---

Working on an application (read: game), and ran into what I'm sure is a common problem. I have a list of assets that will be loaded asynchronously, each of which needs to reference a specific object once created.

See code below. When an image loads, it should create a `Kinetic.Image` object and associate it back to the `this.enemies[n]` that has the correct image URL. `this.enemies` is cardinal, the assets/objects need to stay in that order - so I can't just push the objects to an array as they're created. The list is also variable-length, so I can't just hard-code things out. I even tried referencing the `i` from the loop in an act of desperation, and (not surprisingly) it doesn't work.

I tried googling things like "asynchronous assignment", without much success. Here's the question - when `2.png` loads and creates its object, **how do I use closure** to assign it back to the object containing `asset: "2.png"`? I understand that the linked question is related, but it says nothing about how to execute it when dealing with async loading.

Here's the code:

```
var Battle = {

    ...

    start: function(){
        this.enemies = [
            { asset: "1.png" },
            { asset: "2.png" },
            { asset: "3.png" }
        ];

        for(i in this.enemies){
            var eImg = new Image();
            eImg.onload = function(){
                Battle.enemies[i].obj = new Kinetic.Image({
                    image: eImg,
                    x: 40, y: 40
                });
            };
            eImg.src = "/game/assets/battle/"+this.enemies[i].asset;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that there is a cleaner solution than the ones in the linked QA : using `this.enemies.forEach(function(_, i){...`

Comment: Please reopen this question - the "duplicate" is related but not exact, and I don't understand how to do this in terms of asynchronous requests.

Comment: Put the content of your loop in `this.enemies.forEach(function(_, i){` .. `}`.

Comment: @dystroy it only seems to be iterating the first element of the three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically what they are suggesting:

```
function makeCallback(enemy, eImg) {
    enemy.obj = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: eImg,
        x: 40, y: 40
    });
}

var Battle = {

    ...

    start: function(){
        this.enemies = [
            { asset: "1.png" },
            { asset: "2.png" },
            { asset: "3.png" }
        ];

        for(i in this.enemies){
            var eImg = new Image();
            eImg.onload = makeCallback(this.enemies[i], eImg);
            eImg.src = "/game/assets/battle/"+this.enemies[i].asset;
        }
    }
};
```

With your code, when the function is executed, `i` is whatever its value is at that time, not at the time the function was defined. Use a function to isolate enemy and eImg and close them inside the function object.

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't know it would still work with async loading like that.